# preg_replace all img tags with something else

Tags: php, html, css

so basically what i need to do is replace all

```
<img src="random image goes here" class="random class goes here" alt="random alt goes here" />
```

with

```
<table>
    <a href="#">src="random image goes here" class="random class goes here" alt="random alt goes here" /></a>
</table>
```

in a content. I tried to do it with preg_replace, but without success, maybe you could try helping me?

Here is what I've tried -

```
$content = preg_replace('/"><img class=/', '"><table class="image-caption aligncenter"><tr><td><div><a href="#" target="blank"><img class=', $content);
$content = preg_replace('/ \><\a>/i', ' /></a></div></td></tr></table></a>', $content);
```

Comment: the html for the "with" part is erroneous

Comment: @user1184908: First, `<table>` have to be followed with at least one `<tr>` that has to be followed by at least one `<td>` where all of these tags are pair tags. So the right markup should be `<table><tr><td><a href="#"><img ... /></a></td></tr></table>`.

Comment: Well, yeah just take a look on php code, since I wrote example only there :)

Comment: @user1184908 OK, what about this: `$content = preg_replace('/<img (.*?) \/>/i', '<table><tr><td><a href="#"><img $1 /></a></td></tr></table>', $content);` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lacking a better context:

```
$content = preg_replace(
    '/(<img[^>]+>)/',
    "<table><tr><td><a href=\"#\">$1</a></td></tr></table>",
    $content
);
```

Check http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('/(<img.*>)/', '<table><a href="#">$1</a></table>', $content);
```

I have directly translated your requirement to code. But your HTML in the question is incorrect as table should have atleast on tr and td. Accommodate those in my code and it shoudl work fine

**Edit based on snippet provided in your question below**

```
preg_replace('/(<img.*>)/', '<table><tr><td><div><a href="#" target="blank">$1</a></div></td></tr></table></a>', $content);
```